# Compile deb packages in arm64

Tags: atom, arm64

First of all sorry for my low level of knowledge,I just bought a Pinebook and my Linux knowledge is very simple.

I will like to install Atom text editor in my Ubuntu mate system, but every installation I tried seems to fail since its not made form arm64.

Does anyone how to install it or how to compile the source files? I followed the debian arm64 guide but didn't seems to work neither.
https://wiki.debian.org/Arm64Port#Building_packages

Comment: Can we see a link to that `arm4 guide`?

Comment: iep sorry, forgot to add it!

Comment: try [this](https://gist.github.com/jlord/7ffaf94d041982346934) possible solution, And see the [gist here](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/7822)

Comment: it seems to have some problem with npm install and some deprecated pakages